# iphone: Adding UIRequiredDeviceCapabilitie

Tags: iphone

I am reading the "Device Support - Setting Required Hardware Capabilities" on  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html

I want to add still-camera capability by doing the following:

1. Open my Info.plist
2. Click +
3. Add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities on the Key column
4. Add still-camera on the Value column
5. Save the updated Info.plist

Is this the correct way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Notice that if you install the app using XCode, it can still be installed without any error message. So I think App Store makes some check before installation.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to have the capability to utilize the still camera, you don't have to do anything, except check that the camera exists at runtime:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
  //Something
}
```

This is the correct approach, if your application has utility, even when run on a device without a camera.  If, on the other hand, your App *needs* the camera in order to function, then changing  the plist is the correct approach, as this is a signal to Apple that your App can not be used on a device without a camera.  In that case the procedure you outlined is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing this is part of submission to Apple Store.
Minor corrections after steps 3-4
3 Add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities with value type=Dictionary on the Key column
4 Add another row under UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
   1. Add still-camera with value type=Boolean on the Key column
   2. Check the box on the Value column

Answer (score 1):

Someone at the Developer Forum answered my question.

At the Raw Values/Keys mode

- Click + sign to add a row
- Enter UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
- XCode recognizes the key and automatically creates an item 0

At the "friendly" (Uncheck Raw Values/Keys) mode

- Type "Required device capabilities"
- XCode recognizes it and will auto-complete it

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to set up UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities as a dictionary. It can also be an array. You use a dictionary if some of your options need to be YES and some need to be NO. If you're just trying to set capabilities you require, using an array can be a little simpler.

See "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities " at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html